# llamar variable de controller desde ventana modal con option select LARAVEL

Tags: laravel-8

El error que me muestra laravel al ejecutarse es que la variable $marcas que se encuentra en el documento html createproducto.blame.php dentro de un @foreach para mostrar las marcas de productos en un option de un select, me dice que no esta definida. En la funcion create de mi archivo productocontroller tengo una variable llamada marcas donde almaceno la tabla marcas de mi base de datos.

```html
Este es mi archivo ProductoController

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Producto;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
.
.
.
 public function create()
    {
        $marcas=DB::table('marca');
        $categorias=DB::table('categoria');
        return redirect()->route('producto.index',compact('marcas','categorias'));
    }
.
.
.


este es mi ventana modal que esta en un archivo html

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-create" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <form action="{{route('producto.store')}}" method="POST" files="true">
    @csrf
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Registrar Nueva Producto</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
.
.
.
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="marca">Marca</label>
          <select name="marca" class="form-control">
            <option value="">--Seleccione una Marca--</option>
            @foreach ($marcas as $marca)
                <option value="{{$marca->mar_codigo}}">{{$marca->mar_nombre}}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="categoria">Categoria</label>
          <select name="categoria" class="form-control">
            <option value="">--Seleccione una Categoria--</option>
            @foreach ($categorias as $categoria)
                <option value="{{$categoria->cat_codigo}}">{{$categoria->cat_nombre}}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
.
.
.
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form> 
  </div>
</div>

este es el body de mi index desde donde llamo a mi ventana modal

<body>
        <div class="container">
            <h4>Gestion de Productos</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <form action="{{route('producto.index')}}" method="GET">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 my-1">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="texto" value="{{$texto}}">
                            </div>
                            <!-- <div class="my-1">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Buscar">
                            </div> -->
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button> 
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-create">Nuevo</button> 
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Codigo</th>
                                    <th>Nombre</th>
                                    <th>Marca</th>
                                    <th>Categoria</th>
                                    <th>Precio</th>
                                    <th>Stock</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @if(count($productos)<=0)
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="9">No hay registros</td>
                                </tr>
                            @else
                            @foreach ($productos as $producto)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$producto->prod_codigo}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$producto->prod_nombre}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$producto->marca}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$producto->categoria}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$producto->prod_precio}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$producto->prod_stock}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                @include('Producto.createproducto')
                                @include('Producto.updateproducto')
                                @include('Producto.deleteproducto')
                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        {{$productos->links()}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor agregar el mensaje de error que obtienes tal cual aparece?

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que hayan marcas que no tengan valores asociados a esa llamada que tienes, al tratar de acceder, te da undefined. Trata de asegurarte que tienes valores en esos atributos.

Comment: Intenta poner un ->get() después de (‘marcas’)

Comment: BetaM el mensaje que me muestra es: $marcas is undefined

Comment: Eduardo podrias porfavor decirme en cual archivo agrego ese get, en mi controller, index o ventana modal?

Answer (score 1):

para lanzar valores a un select, se usa un pluck(), esta función te ordena la consulta en forma de lista para que tu select las pueda leer bien y no tenga que desglozar un arreglo más complejo. prueba esto

```
$marcas = DB::table('marca')->pluck('mar_nombre', 'mar_codigo');
```

los valores que van dentro del pluck son los indentificadores y lo que se mostrará respectivamente, para poder recorrerlo en el foreach se usa esta forma:

```
@foreach($marcas as $id => $mar)
<option value="{{$id}}">{{$mar}}</option>
@endforeach
```

aclarar que ese $id puede tener el nombre que te acomode, podria ser $mar_codigo y abajo en el value deberia ser igual. Espero te sirva!! :)

Comment: Claudio Vallejos Silva lo intente y me sigue mostrando que la variable dentro del archivo createproducto.blame.php (ventana modal) is undefined, quizas deberia de hacer alguna referencia en el index primcipal desde donde llamo a la ventana modal donde tengo el option select con mi @foreach ($marcas -> $marca)